# I cannot update the google drive token, it asks me again for consent screen

Tags: vb.net, api, google-drive-api

Good morning, first of all excuse for my English but I do not handle it, I turn to this portal for help.

I am working with VB.net, visual studio 2015.

I am designing my own program that connects to my account's google drive and updates a file. I have the code to log into google drive and so far it does and uploads the file. The first time it is run, the consent screen appears to allow the application and runs perfectly.

The problem is that after a couple of days, it seems that the token expires and no longer connects and the consent screen reappears to allow the application again.

Is there someone who please help me correct my code so that when creating the service an update token is also generated and said consent screen does not appear again.

The code I have is the following with which I create the service, I apologize for my English and low knowledge about programming.

This is the code:

```
Public Sub CreateService()
    Dim ClientId = "my cliente ID"
    Dim ClientSecret = "My secret ID"
    Dim MyUserCredential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {.ClientId = ClientId, .ClientSecret = ClientSecret}, {DriveService.Scope.Drive}, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("Api.google.token")).Result
    moService = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.HttpClientInitializer = MyUserCredential, .ApplicationName = "Actualizar drive"})
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This seems to be due to the status of your GCP project

When you set up your OAuth consent screen:

[image]

If your app is set to "Testing":

> Authorizations by a test user will expire seven days from the time of consent. If your OAuth client requests an offline access type and receives a refresh token, that token will also expire.
>
> [Source](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctesting%2Cin-production)

This is for security purposes, so there is no way to work around that. To extend the life of your token, you would need to publish the app / get it verified. Especially because you are using a

#### User type

You will note that there is a "Internal" user type. This is designed for the type of projects that are just for you or a few people, and is not intended for "publishing" as such. However, this is only available for *paid* Workspace accounts. With these accounts, the tokens last much longer.

#### [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

Apps Script has a more permissive structure allowing you to connect to Drive, for instance, to update a file, which you can easily set on a trigger. Each Apps Script project is set to a default GCP project that you don't need to manage, and these tokens will last. You can attach an Apps Script project to a user-managed GCP project, but then you will have to set up your own consent screen and the tokens will expire.

#### References

- [Unverified Apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)
- [OAuth consent screen and Verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615)
- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)